# can we insert a new opportunityline item using existing pricebook,product,opportunity in apex?

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

can we insert a new opportunity line item using existing price book, product, opportunity through apex code?

if yes, could some one send me a sample code?
I am trying with process builder. But  I don't see any records inserted in opportunity product object.

Comment: @Santanu Boral .  I went through it. But I could see that  we are inserting opportunity,product and price book. In my case I want to use existing PB,Product and opportunity. I am  facing issue  is that I couldn't get price book entryid in my case.  This is the reason behind my question in post.is there any solution? please  suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link:
[How to insert opportunity line item record in salesforce?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Ar3eIAC)